# Terence Tao' analysis 3.4.6. Needed help with exercise specifications

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I've been reading Terence Tao's Real Analysis. Sometimes I don't understand what exactly I am supposed to do with exercise.
Exercise 3.4.6. Prove Lemma 3.4.9. (Hint: start with the set {0, 1}$^X$ and apply
the replacement axiom, replacing each function f with the object $f^{−1}(${1}$)$.)
See also Exercise 3.5.11.

Lemma 3.4.9. Let $X$ be a set. Then the set
{$Y$ : $Y$ is a subset of $X$}
is a set.

Axiom 3.6 (Replacement). Let $A$ be a set. For any object $x ∈ A$, and
any object $y$, suppose we have a statement $P(x, y)$ pertaining to x and
$y$, such that for each $x ∈ A$ there is at most one $y$ for which $P(x, y)$ is
true. Then there exists a set {$y : P(x, y)$ is true for some $x ∈ A$}, such
that for any object $z$,
$z ∈${$y : P(x, y)$ is true for some $x ∈ A$}$
⇐⇒ P(x, z)$ is true for some $x ∈ A$.

How can I prove that {$Y$ : $Y$ is a subset of $X$} is a set? What does it even mean to prove that something is a set?

Answer (score 3):

The statement “$\{y\mid P(y)\}$ is a set” translates to $\exists S \forall y (y \in S \iff P(y))$. If such a set $S$ exists, we can prove it is the only such set (by the axiom of extensionality), and we denote it by $\{y \mid P(y)\}$.

For example, the set $\{x \mid x = 0 \lor x = 1\}$ exists and is equal to $\{0, 1\}$. By contrast, there is no set $\{x \mid x \notin x\}$ (this is known as Russell’s Paradox).

Tao is asking you to show that there is some set $S$ whose elements are exactly the subsets of $X$. In other words, every element of $S$ should be a subset of $X$, and every subset of $X$ should be an element of $S$.

To do this, you should use the axiom scheme of replacement and follow Tao’s hint.